# SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file prueba.py on line 3

Tags: python, non-ascii-characters

I was trying something and I get this error. I searched and i found I have to add # encoding=utf8 but the output was different from what I was expecting

My code:

```
print ' -------\n│      │\n│      │\n│     │\n││      │\n ------'
```

First error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file prueba.py on line 3, but 
no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Code output:

```
-------
Ôöé      Ôöé
Ôöé      Ôöé
Ôöé     Ôöé
ÔöéÔöé      Ôöé
------
```

Comment: I don't have the problem, I can just print it and get the expected result. I guess the problem is you define to use utf8 but don't use a utf8 string. Maybe try to say `print u' -------\n│      │\n│      │\n│     │\n││      │\n ------'`

Comment: thank you so much, I try your solution and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is you define to use utf8 but don't use a utf8 string. Maybe try to say `print u' -------\n│ │\n│ │\n│ │\n││ │\n ------'`

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you might want to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).